# "Subpage" vs "sub page" vs is it even a word?

Tags: terminology

I would go with subpage, but the corrector on stackexchange thinks it's a mistake and shows a red underline. You can try it yourself. Click on "Ask Question" link and type subpage in a sentence to the body textarea.

Why is that? I don't understand. Is subpage a word? Because according to this:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subpage
or 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=subpage
or
http://thesaurus.com/browse/subpage?s=t

It's not even a word!
I don't understand it at all. I and millions are using this term everyday.
Could somebody, please, explain that to me?

Btw. Microsoft is using "subpage" word for Office products instead of "sub page":
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/onenote-help/about-pages-and-subpages-HP001112525.aspx

Comment: It's a word http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpage but not yet in the dictionaries

Comment: I did not downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prefix is defined as :

> A [prefix](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/prefixtext.htm) (affix) is a word, or letter(s) placed at the beginning of
>   another word (a base word) to adjust or qualify its usage or meaning.
>   The opposite of prefix is suffix.

And *sub* as a prefix is defined:

> [**sub-**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sub): 1. a prefix, occurring orig. in loanwords from Latin, with the meanings “under,” “below,” “beneath” (subsoil; subway), “just outside
>   of,” “near” (subalpine; subtropical), “less than,” “not quite”
>   (subhuman; suboscine; subteen), “secondary,” “at a lower point in a
>   hierarchy” (subcommittee; subplot).

So, until we have *'sub page'* entered into the dictionaries, I think it would be a good idea to interpret it like (we do) the words with prefixes.

Comment: The question is not 'If it is allowable what does it mean?' One can't add a prefix to an arbitrarily chosen word and guarantee to end up with another word (in spite of some people's desire for an extremely flexible meaning for 'word'). Perhaps we might produce a - subword.

Comment: With the advent of the web, "page" took on new and different meanings.  Prior to that, a page (of text, that is) was always a single sheet of paper.  Now a page can be dynamic, and therefore a subpage has meaning -- but it has not had such meaning for long, so it can be considered a new word not yet found in dictionaries, and certainly not in automated word checkers.

Comment: "subpage" is much older (early 90's) than "I will google it." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google, (max. 2003 or 2004) which is only a couple years, therefore I don't understand why it is still not in the dictionaries. Oh, I might have an idea... like money and contacts on the right places as usual :)